# How to set a Date Format on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have implemented a calendar application for iPhone.

I am getting the current date using `[NSDate date]`.

Now I want to display only "Tuesday". So how can I get this output. I don't know which format I have to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need NSDateFormatter.

```
NSDateFormatter *dayFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dayFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *formattedDay = [dayFormat stringFromDate:now];
```

See [the Unicode reference](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for all of the format options you can use.